# Passing pointer to ctypes.Structure

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, pywin32

I am trying to figure out how to implement a function that waits for an event to be signaled.
The pointer is returned by a dll function which is a struct that stores 3 items. Two of them which are handles which are just pointers and last is some random unused pointer.
I am really unsure how this is supposed to be formatted as I both have no experienced working with ctypes or events in Windows and I don't know C++.

Right now it does return something but the value in the 3 items in the struct are just small int values(value less than 1000 each). I thought it was the pointer address cut in 3 but it was not.

Anyone can help me figuring out why it doesn't work? I can't figure out what I am doing wrong OR find a DLL I could use to provide a functional example

**Example code**:

```
class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Event1", wintypes.HANDLE),
                ("Event2", wintypes.HANDLE),
                ("Private", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)),
                ]

some_dll_that_returns_the_pointer.restype = ctypes.POINTER(MyStruct)
my_struct = some_dll_that_returns_data() 

while win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects([my_struct.contents.Event1], 0, win32event.INFINITE):
    pass
```

Comment: Looks correct. Are you sure that function returns the correct (waitable) values? What's the actual behavior? Can you show the *C* structure and function prototype (or some documentation)?

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Been going though this multiple times and couldn't wrap my head around why it didn't work.
What i just find weird is that if i look at the my_struct object in PyCharm it does not show the data as a struct, so I would assume you need to unpack the pointer to the struct somehow.

I sadly cannot provide any of the information as it is some of that company internal secret kind of stuff. 
I have also been wondering a lot about if the function even works. But since it works in other cases it must work

Comment: I think with you confirming that my values being correct, I can try to focus on the WaitForMultipleObjects part, I could also be facing that the method is not working and that the pointers is actually returned correctly.

Comment: Try *WaitForSingleObject*, and make sure the objects returned are set by someone. Try with a *C* code. What is the actual / expected behavior?

Comment: Woaaa
If i do:
`test = ctypes.cast(my_struct.contents.Event1, ctypes.c_void_p).value
win32event.WaitForSingleObject(test, win32event.INFINITE)
`
It does actually exit the routine. 
And if i force it to not put any data into the trigger function it also failed my testcase that waits for data.
WOAA it works!

Comment: *WFMO* should work as well. Maybe: `win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects([ctypes.cast(my_struct.contents.Event1, ctypes.c_void_p).value], 0, win32event.INFINITE)`? That's the most generic form, but in this case (only having an object) *WFSO* would be better.

Comment: I do expect to add more handler at some point so if an event is triggered to for example kill the thread it can bypass the method. HUGE thank you for your help!